# Unhelpful HTTP api response from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, nginx

I have an IOS app and I am passing an image with a couple strings to a rails API. I have started getting this error back from the rails. I couldn't find any info on what would be causing this error. I am assuming that it has something to do with passing a larger than average data package (an image)
.

```
{ status code: 500, headers {
    Connection = close;
    Date = "Fri, 15 Jul 2016 20:30:01 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
}
```

Should I be trying to solve this problem from a Client (IOS) or Server (Rails/nginx) perspective?

**Potentially Helpful Info:**

The rails controller api starts with

```
def image_build
    begin
      puts "Begin"
```

But "Begin" is never printed.

**EDIT 1**

Some more info:

in the IOS these lines have the output below:

```
print(response)
print(response.description)
print(response.data)
print(response.request)
print(response.response)
```

output:

```
SUCCESS: 
SUCCESS: 
Optional(<>)
Optional(<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7fa9539506a0> { URL: http://www.example.com/api/image_build })
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fa9515c9cd0> { URL: http://www.example.com/api/image_build } { status code: 500, headers {
    Connection = close;
    Date = "Fri, 15 Jul 2016 20:30:01 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
} })
```

**EDIT 2**

I believe it is just timing out in a sense. When I remove the rails image upload and just have the IOS send the image over it still doesnt work. But if I tell the IOS to not send the image, the strings pass over successfully. So it only fails when the IOS tries to send the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you would get the "puts" response, ideally you should use log statements like `logger.debug` or `logger.info`  and check the log. Depending on which Rails env you are in, if in production it would be log/production.log or log/development.log in development env. It will give you more answers about why you are getting a 500 error.

Comment: If I restart the server and then send the image for the IOS the server never prints anything to the command line. Usually it prints like a 500 or something in the rails. So i get the feeling that rails never gets anything and maybe nginx is the thing erroring. But, ill take a look in the rails logs